# Python code to find the sum of common elements in two sequences of integers in a range

Tags: python

"""A better Python code to find  find the sum of common elements in two     sequences #of integers in a range ??"""

```
#F() constructs a sequence:

def F():
    bot=int(input("Enter start value:")) 
#start value
    top = int(input("Enter stop value:"))
#stop value
    L=range(bot,top+1)
    return(L)
# Let L1 and L2 two sequences
L1=F()
L2=F()
print(L1, L2)


#G()returns the sum of the common elements in L1 and L2:

def G(L1, L2):
    res = []
    for x in L1:
        if x in L2:
            res.append(x)
    return sum(res)
print(G(L1, L2))


# Example: L1=range(1,11), L2=range(5,21): 45(=5+6+7+8+9+10)
```

Comment: `sum(set(L1) & set(L2))` assuming no dupes.  If they are always continuous ranges like in your example code, then you can do even better - just identify the overlap points, and then compute the closed-form arithmetic series.

Comment: What? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If your solution is working, Why looking for a "better Python code"? Your code is good enough. The only change I would do is the list `res`. You don't really need it:

```
def G(L1, L2):
    total = 0
    for x in L1:
        if x in L2:
            total += x
    return total
```

The solution using `set` is good if you are sure that all the elements in L1 and L2 are unique. In this case, because you generated them with a `range`, they are unique, and you could use:

```
sum(set(L1).intersection(set(L2))
```

If there are duplicates, you could filter the elements:

```
sum(filter(lambda x: x in L2, L1))
```

Or you could also use list comprehension:

```
sum([x for x in L1 if x in L2])
```

But I repeat: I think your solution is good Python code.